# set display block to an element found by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, execute-script

I found the elements I'm interested in:

```
LINKS = (By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "link_to")
links = self.browser.find_elements(*self.LINKS)
```

They now have `display` set for `None` and I'd like to show them:

```
for link in links:
  self.browser.execute_script("style.display = 'block';", link)
```

But gives me the js error `style is undefined`. I've tried some things like `link.style.display` or `argument.style.display` but I don't really understand how that should work. Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the element

```
self.browser.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display = "block";'), link)
```

Or if you are not sure `style` attribute exist use `setAttribute()`

```
self.browser.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("style", "display:block");'), link)
```